# Multiple radio buttons, one selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

The title is probably a little vague. So let me explain.

I have a page where users can choose what day they want to have their appointment on. However, we give them multiple choices for this day, incase the first choice was full

The radio button HTML:

```
<input type="radio" class="my-radio" value="monday" name="my_form[day][choice1][]"
id="monday1"/>
<label for="monday1">Monday</label>

<input type="radio" class="my-radio" value="tuesday" name="my_form[day][choice1][]"
id="tuesday1"/>
<label for="tuesday1">Tuesday</label>

<input type="radio" class="my-radio" value="wednesday" name="my_form[day][choice1][]"
id="wednesday1"/>
<label for="wednesday1">Wednesday</label>

<input type="radio" class="my-radio" value="thursday" name="my_form[day][choice1][]"
id="thursday1"/>
<label for="thursday1">Thursday</label>

<input type="radio" class="my-radio" value="friday" name="my_form[day][choice1][]"
id="friday1"/>
<label for="friday1">Friday</label>

<input type="radio" class="my-radio" value="saturday" name="my_form[day][choice1][]"
id="saturday1"/>
<label for="saturday1">Saturday</label>
```

This gets repeated another two times. Though, the ids are changed and the names are aswell. So for the second it would be, (for monday); id=monday2, name=my_form[day][choice2][], and so on.

So to make it clear. 3 rows of radios, all the same values, but ids and names are different.

Now when monday is checked, doesn't matter in which row, I want to disable all other mondays. Now if I instead select Tuesday, all Mondays should be enabled again.

The first part i've got working with jQuery;

```
jQuery('.my-radio').change(function () {
// Get all elements associated to value, but the currently selected radio.
var associates = jQuery('.my-radio[value="' + jQuery(this).val() + '"]').not("#" + jQuery(this).attr('id'));

  // Disable every element that we found
  jQuery(associates).each(function(){
     jQuery(this).prop('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

Now my only problem is the second part. Re-enable the previous disabled radios.

A JSFiddle to make it a little more clear;
http://jsfiddle.net/Hr9h2/1/

Edit:
Thanks alot for the answers.

However, I forgot to mention that you're not allowed to select, for example, Monday three times or even twice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The functionality you're looking for is created by enabling all the radio buttons, and looping over all the checked radio buttons and disabling any that has the same value. That way it works with as many lines of radio buttons you'd like :

```
$('.my-radio').on('change', function () {
    $('.my-radio').prop('disabled',false).filter(':checked').each(function() {
        $('.my-radio[value="' + this.value + '"]:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hr9h2/7/)

Comment: I believe this is the only answer that performs at the OP needed.   All the other answers have been over simplified, destroying the functionality the OP was looking for.   Nicely done!

Comment: @Charlie74 - That's why I posted it, I've created this functionality multiple times before, and if I understood the question correctly, the loop has to be there to make sure it works when checking boxes in all the lines etc.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Apperantly I was thinking a little to hard about it, now I look at it lol. Thanks alot!

Comment: and i doubt you need loop here....using `:checked` .. i agree!!! yes loop is needed .. but if you are getting the elements like the OP.. i don't think loop is needed...the jquery selector will have all the elements..

Comment: @bipen - It's probably somehow possible with a jQuery method that iterates internally instead, but the loop iterates over the checked radios, using each radio value to target any other radios with the same value, so it's not a selector issue! In other words, iteration ***is needed*** for this to work.

Comment: @adeneo .. yup!!! i can see the loop in your case, is there to loop through the checked elements (as i mentioned , in my earlier comments).. and i actually was poiting out to `jQuery(associates).each(function(){` this ... anyways no doubt this is the elegant way to get what OP needs (better than mine) .. :) .. +1 from my side too...

Answer (score 0):

Think it's simple.. just **enable** all radio buttons on its `change` event before disabling particular radio button.

Here's the JS

```
jQuery('.my-radio').change(function () {
    jQuery('.my-radio').prop('disabled', false); //<---here
    // Disable all elements associated to value
    var associates = jQuery('.my-radio[value="' + jQuery(this).val() + '"]').not("#" + jQuery(this).attr('id'));
    associates.prop('disabled', true);
});
```

**NOTE:**

You don't have to use `each` loop to get all the associates. The `associate` variable will already have all the elements. And here's a <kbd>[fiddle at jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Hr9h2/5/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Some more refactoring to the code :

```
$('.my-radio').change(function () {
    //enable all radio buttons
    $(".my-radio").prop("disabled", false);
    // Disable all elements associated to value
    $('.my-radio[value="' + this.value + '"]').not(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: I think you could even use $(".my-radio :checked") to only disable checked/selected radio buttons.

Comment: I don't believe this does what the OP is looking for.   If you test the code, you can now select Monday in all three cases.   See adeneo's solution below...  I believe his is the correct way to do this.

Comment: @Charlie74 could you explain more? "you can now select Monday in all three cases." - what does that mean?

Comment: @hungerpain Try selecting: First Tuesday, next line monday, next line tuesday

Comment: @hungerpain sure...  check this Fiddle here with your code http://jsfiddle.net/Hr9h2/1/    Select options in this order - Choice 1 Monday, Choice 2 Tuesday, Choice 2 Monday, Choice 3 Tuesday, Choice 3 Monday.   The OP is looking to make sure that each day can only be selected once, so that the final selection has three different days selected.   Hope that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
$('.my-radio').click(function () {
    // When a radio button is clicked
    $('.my-radio').each(function () {
        // Enables all radios buttons
        $('.my-radio').prop('disabled', false);
    });

    // Disables all radio buttons with same value as this, except this one
    $('input[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').not(this).prop('disabled', true);

});
```

Comment: `document.getElementById()` when you have jQuery xD

Comment: @kajacx It's faster, if that matters.

Comment: @Campari - Seriously? Why use `document.getElementById($(this).attr('id'))`, it makes no logical sense when you all you need is .`not(this)` !